# DataTrigger does not reevaluate

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I have a ListBox and I want to change the appearance of each ListBoxItem based on the index of the previous ListBoxItem in the ListBox.

In order to do that I have created a CustomListBoxItem which inherits from ListBoxItem and have set a Style for it.

```
Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.ContentTemplateProperty, new CustomListBoxItemContentTemplate());
```

In the constructor of CustomListBoxItemContentTemplate class which inherits from DataTemplate I have a DataTrigger as follows:

```
DataTrigger dt = new DataTrigger();
        dt.Binding = new Binding()
        {
            RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(CustomListBoxItem), 1),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
            Converter = new CustomConverter()
        };
        dt.Value = true;
        Triggers.Add(dt);
```

And finally in the Convert method of the CustomConverter class I have implemented the IValueConverter as follows:

```
        var item = value as CustomBoxItem;

        if (item == null)
            return false;

        /// I get the ItemsControl here
        ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);

        /// and the index of the CustomListBoxItem
        int index = ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);

        if (index == 0) 
            return true;

        var previousItem = ic.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index - 1) as CustomListBoxItem;

        /// ....
```

I should say every thing works perfectly fine in the first place when the ItemsSource is bound to the source collection but when I add or remove items to the CustomListBox, the DataTrigger does not reevaluate the whole items. it does only for the added items.

I really don't know what the problem is, or maybe my approach is not very good to do the job.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? What kind of pattern and change are you doing to the appearance?